# How to implement blink animation in iOS?

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation, core-graphics

I noticed interesting animation effect in iPhone [application](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-memoirs-lite/id609211557?l=en&mt=8). Cell with current date is blinking/flashing when user activate application or touch Today button.

How to implement the same effect? Is it possible to implement it without image resources (for example use only CoreGraphics)?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is too vague. You need to describe the blink effect you want to create. People are unlikely to be familiar with the app you are referring to, and may not want to spend the time to download it. I was curious, and did so. If you update your question so it can be re-opened, I have some suggestions for you, or read codedad's answer. He and I are thinking along the same lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean that effect which 'shines' through the calendar day (by pressing Today).

**1) Creating gradient.**

*Option A*:
To achieve this effect you should create a transparent png with the proper height of the table row. A sample img looks like this (it's only for illustration, pls create one):
[image]

*Option B*: create gradient using CAGradientLayer. Still you have to use an UIImageView to effectively animate the gradient on the cell's row. I would recommend Option A until you don't want to programmatically manipulate gradient visuals.

**2) Placing the image on the row.**

Option A: if you are sure that this animation always takes place on the top row then you can add the gradient image simply over the table.

Option B: (what the mentioned application might uses) you have to place the gradient image inside the cell. Maybe the best choice is to use custom cells (as the mentioned app uses, see the dates on the left in boxes) where you place your gradient image on the left side of the cell (placing X coord = -gradient_img.width).

**3) Animating gradient.**

Start the animation sequence on that action what you would like to link. Eg. I think the app uses the table view's scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation delegate method to trigger the animation.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear 
                 animations:^{                       
                     viewShiningImage.frame = CGRectMake(320, 0, viewShiningImage.frame.size.width, viewShiningImage.frame.size.height);
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     viewShiningImage.frame = CGRectMake(-viewShiningImage.frame.size.width, 0, viewShiningImage.frame.size.width, viewShiningImage.frame.size.height);
                 }
 ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `UIAnimation` and animate the label's alpha property.

Comment: Ok, I will move label use UIAnimation. But how to draw blink?

Comment: @Marta You'll need to do some of the work on your own. I outlined exactly how to do it.

Comment: You should provide an answer to the question, not just a hint

Answer (score 1):

Use timer for continuous blinking effect

```
  mytimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.06f
                                             target:self
                                           selector:
             @selector(willStartBlinkingAnimation)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
```

Write one function which will show/hide your date label. Or else you can set alpha over here, for even time set it to 0.5f, for odd time set it to 1.0f.

```
- (void) willStartBlinkingAnimation {

  [UIView animateWithDuration:1.f
                   animations:^{

                     [currentDateLabel setHidden:![currentDateLabel isHidden]];
  }];
}
```

When you want to stop this process, or at your viewDidUnload method, stop the process and release your timer:

```
[mytimer invalidate];
mytimer = nil;
```

Hope this will help you to fulfill your requirement.

Comment: Isn't that overly complex for just animating opacity back and forth?

Comment: That's why i suggested hidden property as first option